# Execute Oracle cursor with input parameters in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

I am having difficulty figuring out how to add data as input to an Oracle cursor being sent to a stored procedure of a package in PHP.

I am trying to send 2 pieces of data through a cursor. I have verified the data is correct up to sending.

PHP Code:

```
$finalpieces = explode('|',$lkeyarr[$i]); //0=unique id, 1=table
$conn = oci_connect($oracleUsername,$oraclePassword,$oracleService);
$stmt = OCIParse($conn,"BEGIN PROD.PKG_CORE_OBSERVER.StuckPages_Unlock(:cur_PageDetails); END;");
$cur = oci_new_cursor($conn);
OCIBindByName($stmt,':cur_PageDetails',$cur,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);
ociexecute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Stored Procedure Details:

```
PROCEDURE StuckPages_Unlock
    (
      cur_PageDetails IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
```

accepts ref cursor that includes 2 fields:

```
 ProcessID          NUMBER(2);
 PageUniqueID       NUMBER(10);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Ref Cursor is a *pointer* to a result set.  We cannot assign values to a Ref Cursor, we use it with a query:

```
open my_ref_cursor for
    select process_id, page_unique_id
    from some_table;
```

So, your approach is wrong.  It is difficult to be sure what you're trying to achieve but I think what you want is a stored procedure which accepts two parameters that it uses to query a table and return a ref cursor.  Perhaps, something like this:

```
PROCEDURE StuckPages_Unlock
    (
      p_proc_id in some_table.process_id%type
      , p_page_id in some_table.page_unique_id_id%type
      , cur_PageDetails OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) 
IS
    open PageDetails for
        select *
        from some_table
        where process_id = p_proc_id
        and page_unique_id = p_page_id;
END;
```